# Swift: iterating through plist

Tags: ios, nsarray, swift, nsdictionary, plist

I am trying to use a `plist` to hold an array of dictionaries.  Everything seems to be ok except for when I try to iterate through each element of the array.  In this case I an using `NSArray`s and `NSDictionary`s.

In the below example, `albumInfo` is a `NSDictionary`.  The key, `"Title"`  is linked with the a string object.  I am using a method called `addAlbumInfo` which has arguments which are all `String`s except for the `"price:"`

Please help.

```
 var pathToAlbumsPlist:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("AlbumArray", ofType: "plist");
 var defaultAlbumPlist:NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: pathToAlbumsPlist);

 for albumInfo:NSDictionary in defaultAlbumPlist {
     self.addAlbumWithTitle(
         albumInfo["title"],  //Says it is not convertable to a string
         artist: albumInfo["artist"],
         summary: albumInfo["summary"],
         price: albumInfo["price"].floatValue,
         locationInStore: albumInfo["locationInStore"]
     );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the solution I found was to make albumInfo assume a type and then type case each of the values

```
var pathToAlbumsPlist:NSString = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("AlbumArray", ofType: "plist");
var defaultAlbumPlist:NSArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: pathToAlbumsPlist);

for albumInfo in defaultAlbumPlist {
    self.addAlbumWithTitle(albumInfo["title"] as String,
                    artist:albumInfo["artist"] as String,
                   summary:albumInfo["summary"] as String,
                     price:albumInfo["price"] as Float,
           locationInStore:albumInfo["locationInStore"] as String
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since albumInfo is an NSDictionary it can only contain AnyObjects, which means it can't contain a Swift String that is a struct. If your addAlbumWithTitle expects a String and you try to pass it an AnyObject it will give you this error. You can cast `albumInfo["title"]` to a Swift String like this:

```
albumInfo["title"] as String
```

Comment: You may have to cast it as anyobject first. Try `as AnyObject? as String`

Comment: that is so weird but I'll try it

Comment: Still doesn't work.  It says "NSString is not a sybtype of Int".  Not sure why is is mentioning Int....

Comment: do you have an int value in there instead of a string?

Comment: albumInfo["price"] should return a Number

Comment: you shouldn't cast to string and of the ones that return a number

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, But I'm not a fan of all those type castings.  I'll Post my answer.  Please let me know if there is a more elegant way